# Dynamically create private methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, plugins, prototype

I'm creating a jQuery plugin that has an extend function allowing you to essentially create plugins for the plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeBEJ/1/

If you take a look at the fiddle example you will see an `$.fn.wPluginTest.extend` function that allows you to pass in functions to extend the prototype.  Is there anyway to also extend the local namespace to add private methods?

So for instance any functions passed with a `_` in front would be set as private and not available publicly through a PluginTest object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no private properties on javascript objects, and I'd say that it's fine to have them just prefixed with an underscore.

However, you could try:

```
$.fn.wPluginTest.extend = function(funcs) {
    var proto = PluginTest.proto,
        priv = Object.create(proto); // a private namespace inheriting from proto
    for (func in funcs) {
        if (func.charAt(0) != '_')
            PluginTest.prototype[func] = funcs[func].bind(priv);
        else
            priv[func.slice(1)] = funcs[func];
//                   ^^^^^^^^^ not sure, might be confusing
    }
}
```

Yet, those functions will not have access to the `PluginTest` instance they're called on - they're statically bound to the prototype objects - so it's probably a bad idea.

If any plugin needs real privateness, it should utilize variable scoping on its own.

Comment: Hmm, yes might be better for me to approach this problem from the other side and just have any functions that begin with `_` return `null` or something.  All the calls to the plugin are funneled through a getter/setter area anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry about the problem at all. If one of the plugin plugins needs private functions it has to scope them itself; and otherwise you're just copying the public methods.